# Application crashing without internet

Tags: android, android-internet

Here , Basically all i am doing is, checking whether the connection is available or not.If the connection is not available i am redirecting to another activity.That is all.But it keeps crashing.

```
Intent i;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     i = new Intent(Jsouptesting3Activity.this, NoInternet.class);
    Jsouptesting3Activity ob1=new Jsouptesting3Activity();
    ob1.isDataConnectionAvailable(this);
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.way2franchise.com/").get();

        //System.out.println(doc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("cant connect");
        e.printStackTrace();


public  void isDataConnectionAvailable(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info == null)
    {
        System.out.println("No net bob");
         i = new Intent(Jsouptesting3Activity.this, NoInternet.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    System.out.println("YES net bob");
```

While the program executes, i am calling  `isDataConnectionAvailable()` and i have no connection available.So according to the logic it must be redirected  and NoInternet activity should open.
Am i missing anything serious?
 please help.

logcat stack

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1659    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1675 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 121   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 943   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 130 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3701    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 866  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 624 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: your logic is incorrect ... first you do not check what `isDataConnectionAvailable()` return ... second you do not return false if `info` is null, so `Jsoup.connect(...)` is still called ...

Comment: I don't even know where to start, really. There is so much wrong with this code... how can I explain...

Comment: @Wooble i added the logcat stack.

Comment: 1) Creating an instance of an activity manually (ob1): No! 2) Passing `this` as a context to a method of an Activity which subclasses `Context`: No! 3) Believing that `startActivity()` has an immediate effect: Wrong!

Comment: @ClassStacker It is allowed to create an instance of activity manually. 2) why not? Please elaborate.

Comment: it nothing to elaborate about ... this is a basic knowledge about Android platform ... application components like Service, Activity should not be created by `new` but with component specific methods like `startActivity`, `startService` ...

Comment: @PunjanSudhar 1) Creating `ob1` serves no purpose, so let it be. 2) I already motivated this; your `Activity` is the context you should use for this purpose. Passing a useless parameter serves no purpose, so let it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**check isDataConnectionAvailable() as construction if (isDataConnectionAvailable())**

```
 Jsouptesting3Activity ob1=new Jsouptesting3Activity();
   if( ob1.isDataConnectionAvailable(this))
{
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.way2franchise.com/").get();

        //System.out.println(doc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("JSON Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("cant connect");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check isDataConnectionAvailable() as construction `if (isDataConnectionAvailable())`

and I think that the best way is dont check the connection, but check `doc`, if it equals null, then open another activity

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method from the `if` condition so it will not execute

```
if(ob1.isDataConnectionAvailable(this))
{
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.way2franchise.com/").get();

        //System.out.println(doc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("cant connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and return value from `isDataConnectionAvailable(this)`.